# What is the source of this sloka where Vyasa apologises to God for making three errors while writing the Srimad Bhagavatam?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, vyasa

Could someone provide the source of the following sloka where Vyasadeva apologises to God for the following three errors He committed in the Srimad Bhagavatam:

i) He has assumed that God has a form while actually He does not.

ii) He mentioned that God can be praised while He is beyond words.

iii) He has glorified some places as holy while He is all pervading?

I found this sloka is in the footnote of page 152 of Sri Sri Ramakrishna Kathamrita (Akhanda Udbodhan Edition):

> रूपं रूपविवर्जितस्य भवतो ध्यानेन यत्कल्पितं
>   स्तुत्यानिर्वचनीयताऽखिलगुरो दूरीकृता यन्मया
>   व्यापित्वं च निराकृतं भगवतो यत्तीर्थयात्रादिना
>   क्षन्तव्यं जगदीश तद्विकलतादोषत्रयं मत्कृतम्।

Comment: According to this link  its apology of Adi Shankara- https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.97996/page/n193 -see footnote Page 181

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks so much. But he didnt quote the source. In Kathamrita, one pundit says its Byasdeva's. The exact source has to found out.Thanks again.Kind regards

Comment: You should add accurate transliteration while asking source for a source of a shloka. This is now written in Devanagari script which only a few can understand and read. Please add an English transliteration.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, after a simple search, [here's](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.170125/page/n1) another source which doesn't attribute that sloka either to Vyasa or Shankara.

A publication from Tirumala Tirupati Devasthanam (TTD) from 1981 shows this sloka in it's 3rd page... and its attributed to none other than Appayya Dikshitar.

[image: Appayya Dikshitar sloka]

I am less inclined to believe that TTD, with its access to vedic scholars, would go wrong in their attribution. I am, however, not too familiar with the intricacies of what all Appayya Dikshitar wrote. So, may be someone who does have familiarity can find the source work from Dikshitar's works.

Comment: What do you mean by 'none other than'?

Comment: @mohmur Means just that... I was kind of surprised to find that reference but it also made a lot of sense. Take it as more of my mind voice.